# err_connection_refused using socket.IO

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm making a multiplayer game using nodejs with socket.io.

When I'm working on my laptop where the nodejs is running, everything works. I can open multiple window tabs and I have multiple users.

But when I'm trying to connect to my local ip (from the node server) from another laptop next to me, I get an error with the socket.io

```
 "GET http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"
```

code

```
 /**************************************************
** GAME INITIALISATION
**************************************************/
function init() {
// Declare the canvas and rendering context
canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Maximise the canvas
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

// Initialise keyboard controls
keys = new Keys();

// Calculate a random start position for the local player
// The minus 5 (half a player size) stops the player being
// placed right on the egde of the screen
var startX = Math.round(Math.random()*(canvas.width-5)),
    startY = Math.round(Math.random()*(canvas.height-5));

// Initialise the local player
localPlayer = new Player(startX, startY);

socket = io.connect("http://localhost", {port: 8000, transports: ["websocket"]});

remotePlayers = [];

// Start listening for events
setEventHandlers();


};
```

code added

```
  /**************************************************
 ** NODE.JS REQUIREMENTS
   **************************************************/
 var util = require("util"),                    // Utility resources (logging, object inspection, etc)
io = require("socket.io");              // Socket.IO
Player = require("./Player").Player;    // Player class


    /**************************************************
  ** GAME VARIABLES
 **************************************************/
 var socket,        // Socket controller
players;    // Array of connected players


  /**************************************************
   ** GAME INITIALISATION
   **************************************************/
 function init() {
// Create an empty array to store players
players = [];

socket = io.listen(8000);

socket.configure(function()
{
    socket.set("transports", ["websocket"]);
    socket.set("log level", 2);
});

setEventHandlers();
```

};

Comment: have you tried replacing `localhost` with the IP address of the PC on which the nodejs server is running?

Comment: Yes I tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: Try just using "socket = io()" and see what happens.  You shouldn't need to specify the port or even the ip/hostname.  Socket.io is going to make the first connection over the same port as the http request you have already initiated, then it upgrades the connection after talking it over with the server.

Comment: My game won't even work local anymore by doing this. btw I added some code in my question above. In examples over the internet I see them using "var server = require('http').Server(app);" ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I retried replacing localhost with the IP address of the PC on which the nodejs server is running, and it did work.

Answer (score -2):

Here is how I have a working node server set up for socket.io.  Perhaps this will help.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    // on connection from the client this is where you can do stuff like...
    //socket.emit('message', JSON.stringify(yourdataobj));
}
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Then, in the client html (the index.html you served above) here are the following key lines.

In the head section:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Just before the closing body tag:

```
<script>
var socket = io();

socket.on('message', function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
});
</script>
```

Also, refer back to the socket.io site for reminders and refreshers on how to set it all up: http://socket.io/get-started/chat/